# How to make layout like in a photo?

Tags: html, css, layout

I need layout on css like in a photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EASqL.png)

I have html like this. I don't understand now to make layout.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

This is my attempts, but it did'nt work correctly

```
        .list {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            row-gap: 50px;
            column-gap: 30px;


            >li {
                list-style: none;

                &:nth-child(4) {
                    grid-row-start: 2;
                    grid-column-start: 1;
                    grid-column-end: 1;
                }

                &:nth-child(4) {
                    grid-row-start: 2;
                    grid-column-start: 2;
                    grid-column-end: 2;
                }

            }
        }
```

Pleae, help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Grid is a powerful tool, but I think for this particular application you'd be better served with flexbox.

To explain a bit of my snippet:

- You need `flex-wrap: wrap` to make sure it wraps properly rather than just continuing on a single line
- I added a bit of extra CSS into the `li` styles to make it look like you wanted while still using `li` elements (removed bullet points, added gray background for better visibility, added spacing between items, and changed box-sizing so that the margin doesn't make it too wide). I'd probably just use `div`s instead of a list and list items unless there's a semantic reason for it being a list (accessibility, usually)
- `flex-shrink: 0;` means that items won't shrink down to fit and will instead maintain their defined size (in this case, 30% width)

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul.list li {
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li>X</li>
    <li>X</li>
    <li>X</li>
    <li>X</li>
    <li>X</li>
</ul>
```